# Possibility of disabling td and ul using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Can a "td" or "ul" be disabled using jQuery, like we do for textboxes and some other input types.
I tried using "prop" and "attr" jquery functions, but nothing worked.

Is it possible?

Comment: What would "disabling" a `td` or `ul` be?

Comment: like be disable a textbox so that its not accessible, likewise I want to do for td or ul

Comment: Accessible in what way?  Are they links or what?

Comment: no ..they contain jquery autosuggest powered textfield, which i want to be disabled when a user clicks on a radio button.

Comment: *"they contain jquery autosuggest powered textfield"* And you didn't think that was relevant information to put in the question?!

Comment: wow ...no one is giving any input but very much interested in down-voting my question

Comment: `disabled` property only affects form elements but for other dom nodes you can use some css classes to detrmine enable/disabled.

Comment: Look at the tooltip on the downvote button and you'll see why.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok i will..@T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0):

first of all you cannot disable a `td` or `ul`.

If you dont want user to get access of a `td` or `ul` you can hide them or remove them from page.

```
$("td#your_id").hide();

$("ul#someid").hide();
```

or you can remove them from your html

```
$("td#your_id").remove();
$("ul#someid").remove();
```